# Is there a converter from List<CompletionStage> to CompletionStage<List> in Java?

Tags: java, future, completable-future, completion-stage

Like in this hypothetical example of using `of`:

```java
List<CompletionStage<Long>> listOfFutureLongs = getFutureLongs(...)
CompletionStage<List<Long>> futureListOfLongs = CompletionStage.of(listOfFutureLongs)
```

Comment: What should `futureListOfLongs` represent? All `listOfFutureLongs` successfully completed? Any of `listOfFutureLongs` successfully completed?

Comment: The `futureListOfLongs` should be completed when all individual futures are complete. I just want to continue my computations as if I already have all the Longs, i.e.: `futureListOfLongs.andThen(....use my list here ...)`

Answer (score 2):

Strangely no.

There's `CompletableFuture.allOf` for `CompletableFuture`, which is kind of like what you want, but no similar function for `CompletionStage`.

You can either use `CompletionStage.toCompletableFuture` to get futures, or you can write your own.

Unfortunately, the inability to check a `CompletionStage` to see if it's done already means that you can't do this quite as efficiently.

This code is in a not-yet-released (also not yet tested) open source project of mine.  Feel free to use it:

```
public static <T> CompletionStage<List<T>> list(List<CompletionStage<T>> list)
{
    if (list.size() <= 0)
    {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Collections.emptyList());
    }
    if (list.size() == 1)
    {
        return list.get(0).thenApply(Collections::singletonList);
    }
    final AtomicInteger waiters = new AtomicInteger(1);
    final List<T> ret = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
    final AtomicReference<Throwable> retErr = new AtomicReference<>();
    final CompletableFuture<List<T>> retFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
    {
        ret.add(null);
        final int pos = i;
        final CompletionStage<T> cs = list.get(i);
        if (cs == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        waiters.incrementAndGet();
        cs.whenComplete((val, err) -> {
            if (err != null)
            {
                retErr.compareAndSet(null, err);
            }
            ret.set(pos, val);
            _doneListItem(waiters, retFuture, ret, retErr.get());
        });
    }
    _doneListItem(waiters, retFuture, ret, retErr.get());
    return retFuture;
}

private static <T> void _doneListItem(AtomicInteger waitCount, CompletableFuture<List<T>> ret, List<T> val, Throwable err)
{
    if (waitCount.decrementAndGet() == 0)
    {
        if (err != null)
        {
            ret.completeExceptionally(err);
        }
        else
        {
            ret.complete(val);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Internet says, use completable future:

```java
List<CompletionStage<Long>> futureLongs = getFutureLongs();
var arr = futureLongs.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futureLongs.size()]);
CompletionStage<List<Long>> result = CompletableFuture.allOf(arr)
  .thenApply(unused -> futureLongs.stream().map(f -> f.toCompletableFuture().join()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Really the simplest solution, though `futureLongs.toArray(…)` will need to convert the `CompletionStage`s to `CompletableFuture` first, but it can be done easily with `.stream().map(CompletionStage::toCompletableFuture)`.

Comment: Internet also says, don’t use `size()` when using `toArray` on a collection, i.e. use `futureLongs.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]);`. It’s simpler and, perhaps surprisingly, even more efficient. In fact, the guy who wrote [that article](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/)  knows what he’s talking about. But you don’t need to dig through the details. If in doubt, just use the simpler code.

Comment: @Holger Fixed in Java 6. Good find!