# Convert Promise.sequence(promises).map() to CompletableStage API

Tags: java, playframework, promise, completable-future

**Links I have already consulted and did not help me:**

- [Is there a converter from List<CompletionStage> to CompletionStage<List> in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56135121/is-there-a-converter-from-listcompletionstage-to-completionstagelist-in-java)
- https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture/allOf
- https://dzone.com/articles/20-examples-of-using-javas-completablefuture

I am trying to upgrade an existing application from Play framework 2.4 to Play framework 2.5 . This requires to change all `Promise` to `CompletionStage` . So far so good, but I'm in a bit of a pickle for these lines :

```
List<Promise<WSResponse>> promises = new ArrayList<Promise<WSResponse>>();
for (TargetRequest tRequest : targets) {
    promises.add(/*get one promise*/);
}
return Promise.sequence(promises).map(new Function<List<WSResponse>, WSResponse>() {
    @Override
    public WSResponse apply(final List<WSResponse> responses) throws Throwable {
        return responses.isEmpty() ? null : responses.get(0);
    }
});
```

As you can see, these lines go from a `List<Promise<WSResponse>>` to a `Promise<WSResponse>` by first going from a `List<Promise<WSResponse>>` to a `Promise<List<WSResponse>>` and then returning either null if the `List<WSResponse>` is empty or the first one of the list if it is not.

How do I do all that with `CompletableStage` instead of `Promise` ? the `sequence().map()` method is deprecated. I tried some things using `CompletableFuture.allOf()`, `toArray()` and `stream()` but nothing conclusive.

Comment: CompletableFuture implements CompletionStage.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it:

```
    List<CompletionStage<WSResponse>> futures = new ArrayList<CompletionStage<WSResponse>>();
    for (TargetRequest tRequest : targets) {
      futures.add(/*get one future*/);
    }
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]))
        .thenApply(v -> futures.stream().map(t -> t.toCompletableFuture().join())
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .thenApply(responses -> responses.isEmpty() ? null : responses.get(0));
```